# How can I post data to another file and render from it using DomPDF

Tags: php, file-get-contents, dompdf

I'm looking for a procedure to create PDF for some online shop products using DomPDF.

PHP script:

```
<?php
require_once("../../dompdf_config.inc.php");
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'id' => 150
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_contents('product_pdf.php', false, $context);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

After run this script it streams a new PDF document and show content from product_pdf.php file.
In this file that pulls some information from the database, also I echoed **id** from $postdata above **but it can not display inside generated PDF**.
I have tried with GET method:

```
$html = file_get_contents('product_pdf.php?id=150');
```

but it also not working.
Have you any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really only missing a small bit. When you use `file_get_contents()` as you have PHP pulls the file in via the local file system. That means the actual PHP code does not get parsed and what you end up with is a PDF of the source code.

To get the generated HTML you have to pull the document in via a full URL (e.g. http://example.com/product_pdf.php?id=150). What this does is fetch the document via your web server, which will deliver the generated HTML as it does for any request.

So long as the PHP setting `allow_url_fopen` is true (and right now it needs to be in order for dompdf to do anything with remote resources) then you can just do the following:

```
<?php
require_once("../../dompdf_config.inc.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html_file('http://example.com/product_pdf.php');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

I recommend using `$dompdf->load_html_file()` rather than fetching the document into a variable. That will deliver the most predictable results (at least until you have a better understanding of how dompdf works).

Comment: Oh, and though this is the easiest way to get started there are other ways to do what you want. For example, you could rewrite product_pdf.php to use buffering and at the end of the HTML generation capture the buffer to a variable and feed it to dompdf.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a cURL in this case.